# QStackedWidget and subclassed widgets showing when they shouldn't

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm trying to use a QStackedWidget with a custom QWidget subclass. I'm working on a simple kiosk for my house that shows one of a set of widgets when the screen is tapped. This works very well IFF I create all the stacked widgets in the class that contains the QStackedWidget. When I try to add a subclassed QWidget (lots of labels, need a container), then it displays correctly, but whenever setCurrentIndex() == 0, the subclassed QWidget's showEvent() is called. This means that the first showing has two widgets visible (see image below). Because no hideEvent is ever called for my subclassed widget, it remains visible forever. Below though, you can see that hideEvent is called when the index moves away from this widget, though it immediately gets a showEvent again.

I can hide the subclassed QWidget, but it's complicated if I can't tell that the showEvent I'm getting is the one for me, so skipping it is hard.

I see a showEvent in my subclass whenever QStackedWidget's index == 0.

I have included a short example. This example is a subset but will show the issue, as I stripped out some of the extra functions that don't impact the example (MQTT, setters/getters). I'm running KUbuntu 20.04, Qt5.12.1. I have not found a bug report related to this behavior, but I am hoping I just missed it.

**Edited to udpate code examples and debug output**

[image: Showing two overlapped widgets]

HomeInfo.h

```
#ifndef HOMEINFO_H
#define HOMEINFO_H

#include <QtCore/QtCore>
#include <QtGui/QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
#include <QtQmqtt/QtQmqtt>

#include "resizelabel.h"
#include "trafficlightwidget.h"
#include "weatherwidget.h"

class HomeInfo : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit HomeInfo(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~HomeInfo() override;
    
protected:
    bool event(QEvent *e) override;
    
private:
    QLabel *m_wallClockLabel;
    QLabel *m_dateLabel;
    QLabel *m_officeHumidityLabel;
    QLabel *m_officeTempLabel;
    QLabel *m_atmosphericPressureLabel;
    QLabel *m_basementHumidityLabel;
    QLabel *m_basementHumidityLabelName;
    QLabel *m_basementTemperatureLabel;
    QLabel *m_basementTemperatureLabelName;
    QWidget *m_trafficLight;
    QStackedWidget *m_stack;
    QWidget *m_clockGridWidget;
    QGridLayout *m_clockWidgetLayout;
    QWidget *m_houseGridWidget;
    QGridLayout *m_houseGridLayout;
    WeatherWidget *m_weatherWidget;
};

#endif // HOMEINFO_H
```

main application HomeInfo.cpp

```
#include "homeinfo.h"

HomeInfo::HomeInfo(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QPalette pal(QColor(0,0,0));
    setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Window);
    pal.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::black);
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
    setPalette(pal);
    
    QFont c("Roboto-Regular", 84);
    c.setBold(true);
    QFont d("Roboto-Regular", 32);
    QFont t("Roboto-Regular", 24);
    QFont n("Roboto-Regular", 18);
    
    m_stack = new QStackedWidget(this);
    m_clockGridWidget = new QWidget();
    m_clockWidgetLayout = new QGridLayout(m_clockGridWidget);
    m_wallClockLabel = new QLabel();
    m_wallClockLabel->setScaledContents(true);
    m_wallClockLabel->setFont(c);
    m_wallClockLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_dateLabel = new QLabel();
    m_dateLabel->setScaledContents(true);
    m_dateLabel->setFont(d);
    m_dateLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_officeHumidityLabel = new QLabel();
    m_officeHumidityLabel->setScaledContents(true);
    m_officeHumidityLabel->setFont(t);
    m_officeHumidityLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_officeTempLabel = new QLabel();
    m_officeTempLabel->setScaledContents(true);
    m_officeTempLabel->setFont(t);
    m_officeTempLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_trafficLight = new QWidget();
    m_clockWidgetLayout->setHorizontalSpacing(20);
    m_clockWidgetLayout->addWidget(m_wallClockLabel, 0, 0, 3, 6);
    m_clockWidgetLayout->addWidget(m_officeTempLabel, 3, 0, 1, 3);
    m_clockWidgetLayout->addWidget(m_officeHumidityLabel, 3, 3, 1, 3);
    m_clockWidgetLayout->addWidget(m_trafficLight, 3, 5, 3, 1);
    m_clockWidgetLayout->addWidget(m_dateLabel, 4, 0, 2, 5);

    m_basementHumidityLabel = new QLabel();
    m_basementHumidityLabel->setScaledContents(true);
    m_basementHumidityLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_basementHumidityLabel->setFont(t);
    m_basementTemperatureLabel = new QLabel();
    m_basementTemperatureLabel->setScaledContents(true);
    m_basementTemperatureLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_basementTemperatureLabel->setFont(t);
    m_basementTemperatureLabelName = new QLabel("Basement Temp");
    m_basementTemperatureLabelName->setFont(n);
    m_basementHumidityLabelName = new QLabel("Basement Humidity");
    m_basementHumidityLabelName->setFont(n);
    m_houseGridWidget = new QWidget();
    m_houseGridLayout = new QGridLayout(m_houseGridWidget);
    
    m_houseGridLayout->addWidget(m_basementTemperatureLabelName, 0, 0);
    m_houseGridLayout->addWidget(m_basementHumidityLabelName, 0, 1);
    m_houseGridLayout->addWidget(m_basementTemperatureLabel, 1, 0);
    m_houseGridLayout->addWidget(m_basementHumidityLabel, 1, 1);
    
    connect(m_stack, &QStackedWidget::currentChanged, this, &HomeInfo::stackWidgetChanged);

    m_weatherWidget = new WeatherWidget();
    m_weatherWidget->setVisible(false);
    m_stack->addWidget(m_clockGridWidget);
    m_stack->addWidget(m_houseGridWidget);
    m_stack->addWidget(m_weatherWidget);
    setCentralWidget(m_stack);
}

HomeInfo::~HomeInfo() = default;

void HomeInfo::stackWidgetChanged(int index)
{
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    Q_UNUSED(index)
}

bool HomeInfo::event(QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) {
        qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
        if (m_stack->currentIndex() == (m_stack->count() - 1)) {
            m_stack->setCurrentIndex(0);
        }
        else {
            m_stack->setCurrentIndex(m_stack->currentIndex() + 1);
        }
        return true;
    }
        
    return QMainWindow::event(e);
}
```

WeatherWidget.h

```
#ifndef WEATHERWIDGET_H
#define WEATHERWIDGET_H

#include <QtCore/QtCore>
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>

class WeatherWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    WeatherWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~WeatherWidget() override;

protected:
    void hideEvent(QHideEvent *event) override;
    void showEvent(QShowEvent *event) override;
    
private:
    QLabel *m_outdoorTemperatureLabel;
    QLabel *m_outdoorTemperatureTextLabel;
    QLabel *m_outdoorHumidityLabel;
    QLabel *m_outdoorHumidityTextLabel;
    QLabel *m_luxLabel;
    QLabel *m_luxTextLabel;
    QLabel *m_uvRawLabel;
    QLabel *m_uvRawTextLabel;
    QLabel *m_uvIndexLabel;
    QLabel *m_uvIndexTextLabel;
    QLabel *m_rainTodayLabel;
    QLabel *m_rainTodayTextLabel;
    QLabel *m_totalRainLabel;
    QLabel *m_totalRainTextLabel;
    QLabel *m_airPressureMercuryLabel;
    QLabel *m_airPressureMercuryTextLabel;
    QLabel *m_airPressureTrendLabel;
    QLabel *m_airPressureTrendTextLabel;
    QGridLayout *m_layout;
};

#endif // WEATHERWIDGET_H
```

WeatherWidget.cpp

```
#include "weatherwidget.h"

WeatherWidget::WeatherWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QDate now = QDate::currentDate();
    
    QFont text("Roboto-Sans", 14);
    QFont content("Roboto-Sans", 20);
    
    m_outdoorTemperatureLabel = new QLabel();
    m_outdoorTemperatureLabel->setFont(content);
    m_outdoorTemperatureLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_outdoorHumidityLabel = new QLabel();
    m_outdoorHumidityLabel->setFont(content);
    m_outdoorHumidityLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_luxLabel = new QLabel();
    m_luxLabel->setFont(content);
    m_luxLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_uvIndexLabel = new QLabel();
    m_uvIndexLabel->setFont(content);
    m_uvIndexLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_rainTodayLabel = new QLabel();
    m_rainTodayLabel->setFont(content);
    m_rainTodayLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_totalRainLabel = new QLabel();
    m_totalRainLabel->setFont(content);
    m_totalRainLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_airPressureMercuryLabel = new QLabel();
    m_airPressureMercuryLabel->setFont(content);
    m_airPressureMercuryLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_airPressureTrendLabel = new QLabel();
    m_airPressureTrendLabel->setFont(content);
    m_airPressureTrendLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_outdoorTemperatureTextLabel = new QLabel("Temperature");
    m_outdoorTemperatureTextLabel->setFont(text);
    m_outdoorTemperatureTextLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_outdoorHumidityTextLabel = new QLabel("Humidity");
    m_outdoorHumidityTextLabel->setFont(text);
    m_outdoorHumidityTextLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_luxTextLabel = new QLabel("Brightness");
    m_luxTextLabel->setFont(text);
    m_luxTextLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_uvIndexTextLabel = new QLabel("UV Index");
    m_uvIndexTextLabel->setFont(text);
    m_uvIndexTextLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_rainTodayTextLabel = new QLabel("Rainfall Today");
    m_rainTodayTextLabel->setFont(text);
    m_rainTodayTextLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_totalRainTextLabel = new QLabel();
    m_totalRainTextLabel->setFont(text);
    m_totalRainTextLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_airPressureMercuryTextLabel = new QLabel("Air Pressure");
    m_airPressureMercuryTextLabel->setFont(text);
    m_airPressureMercuryTextLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_airPressureTrendTextLabel = new QLabel("Air Pressure Trend");
    m_airPressureTrendTextLabel->setFont(text);
    m_airPressureTrendTextLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_outdoorTemperatureTextLabel, 0, 0);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_outdoorTemperatureLabel, 1, 0);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_outdoorHumidityTextLabel, 0, 1);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_outdoorHumidityLabel, 1, 1);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_airPressureMercuryTextLabel, 0, 2);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_airPressureMercuryLabel, 1, 2);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_luxTextLabel, 2, 0);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_luxLabel, 3, 0);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_uvIndexTextLabel, 2, 1);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_uvIndexLabel, 3, 1);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_airPressureTrendTextLabel, 2, 2);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_airPressureTrendLabel, 3, 2);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_rainTodayTextLabel, 4, 0);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_rainTodayLabel, 5, 0);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_totalRainTextLabel, 4, 1);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_rainTodayLabel, 5, 1);
    
    setLayout(m_layout);
    m_totalRainTextLabel->setText(QString("%1 Rainfall").arg(now.year()));
}

WeatherWidget::~WeatherWidget()
{
}

void WeatherWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent* event)
{
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}

void WeatherWidget::hideEvent(QHideEvent* event)
{
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "homeinfo.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    HomeInfo w;
    app.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::BlankCursor));
    w.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 480);
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Debug output

````
void HomeInfo::stackWidgetChanged(int) : Index 0 // constructor
virtual void WeatherWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent*) // constructor
virtual bool HomeInfo::event(QEvent*) // touchevent
void HomeInfo::stackWidgetChanged(int) : Index 1
virtual bool HomeInfo::event(QEvent*) //touchevent
void HomeInfo::stackWidgetChanged(int) : Index 2
virtual bool HomeInfo::event(QEvent*) // touchevent
virtual void WeatherWidget::hideEvent(QHideEvent*) //WeatherWidget gets hidden
void HomeInfo::stackWidgetChanged(int) : Index 0 // signal that index changed to HomeInfo
virtual void WeatherWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent*) // WeatherWidget gets another showEvent
virtual void WeatherWidget::hideEvent(QHideEvent*) // after X closes window
virtual void WeatherWidget::hideEvent(QHideEvent*) // after X closes window
*** Exited normally ***```
````

Comment: Are you sure your debug output is correct? Or the comments? It seems funny that you `// switch to m_weatherWidget` and then next thing to happen is `WeatherWidget::hideEvent`...

Comment: Also, if widget is hidden, its children are also hidden, so you don't need to hide or show them explicitly, like you seem to do here. Does it work if you just remove the `WeatherWidget` event handlers?

Comment: @hyde, those hideEvents happen later, not immediately, when I close the application. I included them to show the hideEvent does happen, just not when the widget is constructed. And yes, without the event handlers, the same behavior is evident. I added them to try to figure out what was happening and try to control the labels, which is where I learned showEvent is being called when the widget is not on top of the stackWidget. The debug output is from the program, so I'm not sure how it could be incorrect. I'm updating the debug output to show a bit more detail.

Comment: I think I've figured it out, but I'm still digging a bit. If you update labels in a hidden widget, they will force a showEvent it seems. I am testing, but it doesn't seem to be every label that causes this. Since I have an MQTT listener going and updating hidden labels all the time, I see hidden widgets. Calling hide() in the update function in the widget means I do not see them. But it's not consistent exactly, so I have to do some digging to figure out what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 1):

No, this was just a dumb mistake. I used autocomplete when I attempted to type setLux() in HomeInfo.cpp (not visible, I removed the MQTT functions), and what I got was setVisible(). This meant that every time I got a new value for how bright it is outside, it was setVisible(true) on the widget when the double was implicitly cast to true. I would have expected a warning from gcc, but either warnings are turned off, or it wasn't generated. Ah well, this was not a QT bug or odd unexpected behavior, it was a mistake in my code.